# Textboxes are not filled

Tags: asp.net

I am creating a content web page which is inherited from `BasePage`. There is a drop down on the page. On `selectedindexchanged` of dropdown, I'm filling some values in text boxes on the page. No error is coming. Even when debugging by applying breakpoint on `selectedindexchanged`, everything seems fine. But textboxes are empty after page load.

Comment: some code might help? We can't be sure that you are filling the values properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you could tap into the PreRender event, put a breakpoint there, and use the immediate window to evaluate the textbox's text value, to see if they still exist?  Also check what else might be setting textbox Text property.

Lastly, if you are using an update panel, ensure the textboxes are also in that updatepanel region.